# Question About The Sequence Of Calls To Request/Free MSI-X Interrupt Resource On FreeBSD

Tags: interrupt, freebsd, power-management, pci-e

I have some questions about the sequence of calls to request/free MSI-X interrupt resource on FreeBSD.

I tried "amd64 FreeBSD 13.1" and "amd64 FreeBSD 13.2".

When requesting MSI-X interrupt resource, I tried the following 2 sequences:

****Sequence A***:

```
bus_alloc_resource

pci_msix_count

pci_alloc_msix

bus_setup_intr
```

****Sequence B***:

```
pci_msix_count

pci_alloc_msix

bus_alloc_resource

bus_setup_intr
```

When using "***Sequence A***", I observed bus_alloc_resource FAIL (return NULL pointer).

When using "***Sequence B***", it works so I choose "Sequence B".

When freeing MSI-X interrupt resource, I tried the following 2 sequences:

****Sequence C***:

```
bus_teardown_intr

pci_release_msi

bus_release_resource
```

****Sequence D***:

```
bus_teardown_intr

bus_release_resource

pci_release_msi
```

When using "***Sequence C***", I observed one system log "Device leaked MSI vectors" when unloading the device driver.

When using "***Sequence D***", I observed "sudo acpiconf -s 3" is no longer able to suspend system to RAM.

Related man:
https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pci_release_msi&sektion=9&manpath=freebsd-release-ports

[screenshot photo for man page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOcRC.png)

According to the man, "***Sequence A***" and "***Sequence C***" are correct.
However, "***Sequence A***" and "***Sequence C***" have problems as shown above.

Can advice what is the cause of the problems?

Or is there a workaround solution available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question quiet specific, I'd rather go to https://lists.freebsd.org/archives/freebsd-questions/.